# Copy files renaming if already exists PowerShell

Tags: powershell, copy, rename, auto-increment

This script works to rename files while copying them if they are duplicates.  I need to rename the current destination file first then copy the source file as is.  Any ideas?

```
function Copy-FilesWithVersioning{
    Param(
        [string]$source,
        [string]$destination
    )
    Get-ChildItem -Path $source -File
        ForEach-Object {
            $destinationFile = Join-Path $destination $file.Name
            if ($f = Get-Item $destinationFile -EA 0) {
                # loop for number goes here
                $i = 1
                $newname = $f.Name -replace $f.BaseName, "$($f.BaseName)_$I")
                Rename-Item $destinationFile $newName
            }
            Copy-Item $_ $destination
        }
}

Copy-FilesWithVersioning c:\scripts\Source c:\scripts\DestinationA
```

Errors:

```
At line:10 char:53
+             if($f = Get-Item $destinationFile -EA 0){
+                                                     ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At line:8 char:23
+         ForEach-Object{
+                       ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At line:2 char:34
+ function Copy-FilesWithVersioning{
+                                  ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At line:13 char:77
+ ...         $newname = $f.Name -replace $f.BaseName, "$($f.BaseName)_$I")
+                                                                         ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:15 char:13
+             }
+             ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
At line:17 char:9
+         }
+         ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
At line:18 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and what I did was always create a new file insert a node in the name with the date/time format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.  So foo.txt was copied first as foo.2018-08-29T12:34.45.txt so I have an archived copy of the file, then copied as foo.txt.  Alternately you could call TEST-PATH and do a rename similar to this when you copy documents.  Depends on how many duplicates you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you No Refunds, we have a application that is looking for a specific file name and it picks it up.  so when I add a new Version of the file it ignores the files with -# after the name and imports only the new files.  I agree the whole process needs to be improved but that is not my department.

Comment: unless `#` is representing just actual single digits you can replace with ticks like (Get-Date).Ticks as the part after your dash.  You can convert it back to the real date any time you want and still have them sorted by date/time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code from this link: https://www.pdq.com/blog/copy-individual-files-and-rename-duplicates/:

```
$SourceFile = "C:\Temp\File.txt"
$DestinationFile = "C:\Temp\NonexistentDirectory\File.txt"

If (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {
    $i = 0
    While (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {
        $i += 1
        $DestinationFile = "C:\Temp\NonexistentDirectory\File$i.txt"
    }
} Else {
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path $DestinationFile -Force
}

Copy-Item -Path $SourceFile -Destination $DestinationFile -Force
```

Answer (score 2):

The errors you're seeing are caused by the spurious closing parenthesis in this line:

```
$newname = $f.Name -replace $f.BaseName, "$($f.BaseName)_$I")
```

Remove the parenthesis from the end of the line and these errors will disappear.

There are several other mistakes in your code, though, so even with that fixed the code still won't work.

- You're missing a pipe between the `Get-ChildItem` and `ForEach-Object`. It's required for passing the output of one cmdlet to the other.

  ```
  Get-ChildItem -Path $source -File |
      ForEach-Object {
          ...
      }
  ```
- The variable `$file` is undefined. In a PowerShell pipeline you want to work with the "current object" variable (`$_`). Change this line

  ```
  $destinationFile = Join-Path $destination $file.Name
  ```

  into

  ```
  $destinationFile = Join-Path $destination $_.Name
  ```
- `$_` in the statement

  ```
  Copy-Item $_ $destination
  ```

  is expanded to just the name of the file, not the full path. Change that into

  ```
  Copy-Item $_.FullName $destination
  ```

  Better yet, move the `Copy-Item` statement *after* the `ForEach-Object`, so you don't need to explicitly specify the source in the first place (the cmdlet reads input from the pipeline):

  ```
  Get-ChildItem ... | ForEach-Object {
      ...
      $_   # need this line to pass the current object back into the pipeline
  } | Copy-Item -Destination $destination
  ```

  Note that you *must* output the current object back to the pipeline and specify the destination as a named parameter (`-Destination $destination`) for the latter to work.
- Your check for the presence of a file in the destination folder is a little awkward. Use `Test-Path` instead. You can construct the new filename from the current object.

  ```
  if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $destinationFile) {
      $i = 1
      Rename-Item $destinationFile ($_.BaseName + "_$i" + $_.Extension)
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I settled on the option to create my own script. It supports specifying destination directory or file name. Requires Powershell Core.

```
param(
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true)] $path,
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true)] $destination
)

Function FindUniqueFileName($fileName) {
    $result = $fileName
    $i = 0
    While (Test-Path $result -PathType Leaf) {
        $i += 1
        $parentPath = Split-Path $fileName -Parent
        $fileNameBase = Split-Path $fileName -LeafBase
        $extension = Split-Path $fileName -Extension
        $establishedFileName = $fileNameBase + " ($i)" + $extension
        $result = Join-Path $parentPath $establishedFileName
    }
    return $result
}

If (!(Test-Path $path -PathType Leaf)) {
    throw "Source file $path does not exist"
}

$destinationFileName = (Test-Path $destination -PathType Container) `
    ? (Join-Path $destination (Split-Path $path -Leaf))
    : $destination

$uniqueFileName = FindUniqueFileName $destinationFileName

Copy-Item -Path $path -Destination $uniqueFileName -Force
```